# Capturing propagated events in parent components

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that has a child component that has an input textbox.  I noticed that the keyup event is propagated upwards and I can bind to it even in my root component.  When the user types in the box I get a KeyboardEvent when I bind to (keyup) that I can capture in my root component without doing anything additional.

So when a text change occurs what should I be doing?  Should I be emitting custom events that are already natively supported by the child components such as keyup, keydown etc.?

For example should I have a:

```
@Output() textChange$ = new EventEmitter()
```

in my child component and capture the keyup and emit the textChange event and then bind to the (textChange) or is it ok to just avoid it since it is redundant.  The reason I ask is that I am unsure if the propagation upwards of native events from children to the top level parent is consistent in all cases.

Is event propagation in Angular 4 consistent with standard browser event propagation behavior.

Comment: EventEmitter doesn't bubble up like normal DOM events if that's what you mean. See [this](https://netbasal.com/event-emitters-in-angular-13e84ee8d28c#11d4)

Answer (score -1):

Angular made JavaScript developer life easier with lambda, parent-child relationship and object passing as parameter.

This is all upto your requirement and implementation part.

Also this a good practice to let parent handle all the events of its child. So we can easily use or modify same parameter in the parent component.